# Video Streaming over bluetooth application

Tags: android, streaming, bluetooth

Hey i want to develop a video streaming over bluetooth application on Android as platform ,my question is that is it possible to stream a video over bluetooth between two android phones ..by making one as server..that is source and other as sink/receiver and is VDP i.e Video Distribution Profile is supported by android apis ? is the scenario materialistic to implement ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no VDP apis in Android